# How to get parent menu name in typo3 neos

Tags: neoscms

How to get parent menu name in typo3-neos

is there any solution ?

```
> <f:render section="itemList" arguments="{items: items, site: site}" />
> 
>   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
>     <f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="menuItemIterator">
>       <f:if condition="{menuItemIterator.cycle} != {menuItemIterator.total}">
>         <li class="{item.state}">
>            <neos:link.node node="{item.node}">{item.label}
>         </li>
>       </f:if>
>    </f:for>
>   </ul>
> </f:section>
```

Comment: Please specify in more details!!

Answer (score 0):

use 
   `<f:debug>{items}</f:debug>.`
There should be parent node name.

Comment: or ${q(node).parents()} will return all parent nodes of current node

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

**1. TypoScript > /Packages/Sites/Your.Package/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts:**

```
body {

  ${q(node).parent().property('title')}

}
```

**2. HTML Template > /Packages/Sites/Your.Package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html**

```
{parentTitle}

{parts.leftMenu -> f:format.raw()}
```

...

Hope this will help you.

TC

Sanjay